# Disabling elements with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When disabling elements, is there a difference between the following:

```
<input type="text" disabled>
```

And:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled">
```

Specifically, when using jQuery to change the disabled property, will it work as expected for both elements?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? Seems like a simple experiment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why disabled="disabled" and not disabled="!"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531738/why-disabled-disabled-and-not-disabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery to change the disabled property, it will work as expected.

A quote from another answered question:
[Why do we need disabled="disabled"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531738/why-disabled-disabled-and-not-disabled#answer-6531804)

> There is an official spec which says you must use that full syntax.
>   But it only applies to xhtml documents. You can find it here (if you
>   search for disabled in that page, you will find that it is listed as
>   only allowing "disabled" as the value. Similarly for the readonly and
>   checked attributes).
>
> Plain HTML - both v4 and v5 - isn't tied to XML's restrictions in this
>   way, and doesn't require an attribute value for disabled; the mere
>   existence of the disabled attribute is sufficient to disable the
>   field, regardless of whether you have a value for the attribute, or
>   what that value is.
>
> The final upshot of all this is that if you are using an XHTML
>   doctype, or you wish to remain XML-compliant, you should use
>   disabled="disabled". If you're not using XHTML and you don't care
>   about having valid XML syntax, then you can just use disabled on its
>   own, or with any attribute value you like.